# How to enumerate running/open apps in app order with applescript?

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

My end goal is to determine the most-recently-used web browser. I.e., a user may have both Safari and Firefox running, but which were they using most recently?

And so, I'm trying to enumerate the open apps, ordered by their window / visibility.

Does Cocoa / Applescript offer a way to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSWorkspace's [`runningApplications`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/runningApplications) method and NSRunningApplication's [`launchDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSRunningApplication/launchDate) property to get you close to what you need.

Check out what the output if this code bit looks like in your console:

```
NSArray * arrayOfRunningApps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
if(arrayOfRunningApps)
{
    for(NSRunningApplication * aUserApp in arrayOfRunningApps) 
    {
        NSLog( @"%@ launch time is %@", [aUserApp localizedName], [aUserApp.launchDate description] );
    }
}
```

As for sorting on some criteria, that's really up to your implementation to do.

A couple caveats:  these api's were introduced as of Snow Leopard (10.6) and 
they only work on apps that the user can see (in the dock), not UNIX processes or admin/root daemons or whatever.

And I'm not certain about Applescript yet, but I'm hoping you'll be able to use this information to get to where you need to go.

Comment: Interesting. But do you know of any API to determine the app order? (I.e., that Safari is in front of Firefox?)